# I need the capability of running a software locally remotelly and be able to acess it depending on whether I have internet connection or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, cloud, local, hybrid

So I am an intern at a Startup company that's providing agricultural solutions to remote areas of our country. The project consists of a private network we run, covering the entire farm, so the farmer can operate quickly from within the farm. Now we're trying to transition into the cloud so that if the client has internet access on the farm, he can operate it remotely.

Because of this, we have the requirement of having a constantly running frontend/backend on the farm. The current solution we came up with was also running a server with frontend/backend on AWS, this software would then have to try and connect to the server running on the farm so the farmer could operate it remotely. But this seems extremely hacky, for example, if internet connection on the farm eventually dropped, the farmer would have to switch into the private network manually (many wouldn't know how to do this), and also, we would have to maintain two instances of the same frontend running in the cloud and locally, this totally seems like a hack..
We're completely out of ideas though and at a loss of how to proceed.

Comment: Can you use AppSync? If no internet connection, it will sync local data as soon as the connection re-establishes.

Comment: I can, that would be nice.